# Colouring a verse based on the gender

Tags: html, css, angular

I have to make a list in which the lines with gender - male will be green and gender - female will be yellow (so far I have everything yellow). I've tried with some condition, assignment, but I'm still at the starting point. Could someone direct me?

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 pt-5 text-right">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClickAddTodo()">Add Todo</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 pt-2">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead class="table-primary">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Email</th>
          <th scope="col">Street</th>
          <th scope="col">Gender</th>
          <th scope="col">Phone</th>
          <th scope="col" class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let todo of todos" style="background-color:yellow;">
          <td class="text-center">{{todo.id}}</td>
          <td>{{todo.firstName}}</td>
          <td>{{todo.lastName}}</td>
          <td>{{todo.email}}</td>
          <td>{{todo.street}}</td>
          <td>{{todo.gender}}</td>
          <td>{{todo.phone}}</td>
          
          <td width="150" class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2" (click)="onClickEditTodoDetail(todo.id)">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="onClickTodoDelete(todo.id)">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should add the angular tag as well, since you are using it!

Comment: If your app is not just a training subject, I am assuming that users of your app are using this information to address those people correctly in communication over phone or mail and make them feel more welcome and improve their experience?
If so, you might also be aware that gender is not binary and that you will make some people feel left out and excluded. So why not go all the way and allow free-text for the gender field as well?
If the purpose of this information is not to improve their experience, I recommend you remove that sensitive piece of personal information altogether. #gdpr

Answer (score 1):

Where you change your `td` background-color, you should add a condition, like this: 
Instead of this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let todo of todos" style="background-color:yellow;">
```

Make it like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let todo of todos" [style.background]="todo.gender == 'Female' ? 'yellow' : 'green'>
```